# Store information about guest in Spring SecurityContextHolder

Tags: spring, session, servlets

I would like to add guests functionality: this means guests are objects that act like users, but are not persisted and have `ROLE_GUEST` instead of `ROLE_USER`. I would like to store a guestID in the session so when the guest does something, I can retrieve the guest and undertake action under the guest's name. How would I add this info if I want to keep a `Stateless Servlet`.

My current login for a registered user is like this:

```
auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, auths);
Authentication result = authManager.authenticate(auth);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
```

I'm looking for something either similar to this or a way to add the guest name somewhere in the SecurityContextHolder.getContext() directly. Can I maybe get the spring `Session` object or another session to store this info?

I'm not using `Spring MVC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the fake `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` you should use the [anonymous authentication mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/anonymous.html) provided by the framework. You can configure it using the security namespace:

```
<security:http ....>
    ....
    <security:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST"/>
</security:http>
```

This will cause the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` to place an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` with the provided name and role into the security context. (Of course, this will only happen if other filters like the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` were unable to authenticate the user.)

Comment: In this configuration the name of the guest is fixed and there is no way to distinguish between guests. I'm looking for a way to attach a unique guest name to them.

Comment: How do you obtain a unique name for an unauthenticated request?

Comment: I have a UserManager that has a list of guests, a new name is created as follows: String guestName = "guest"+random.Int(); If the guestname is already in the list, another guestname is tried. A guestname that is older than 24h is removed from the list.

What I'm actually looking for is a way to attach the guestName to the session, and detect when the session is broken to delete the guestName. But I don't know how...

Comment: Why don't you just set a session attribute? The session will last while the user browses anonymously, and gets automatically invalidated if it logs in. If you want to get notified about session lifecycle events, you need to register a `HttpSessionListener` in your web.xml.

Comment: You last comment is pretty much the answer I was looking for, Thanks. About quote "The session will last while the user browses anonymously, and gets automatically invalidated if it logs in." You mean that when a user gets authenticated a new session is created?

Comment: Most definitely. Otherwise it would be possible to perform a session fixation attack. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-fixation